# Factor a small piece of HTML [django]

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

Can I factor a small piece of html code with Django template ?

I have, for example, a lot of images like this:

```
<img src="/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxx.jpg">
```

Can I replace that by `{{ image_xxx }}` ?

Comment: Yes, but is there a particular need, other than aesthetic reasons?

Comment: Any solution is not going to make your template faster though (as it takes time to process the variables/tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def image_by_value(value):
    return "/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxx.jpg"
```

You can use this in your template as follows:

```
<img src="{% image_by_value 001 %}">
```

The value `001` is then passed to the variable `value` and you can use it to construct the string that contains the image path (i.e., `"/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxx.jpg"`).

Comment: I would rather use inclusion tags - and render the actual html in the tag.

Comment: i use it like that :  { image_by_value|img } ?

Comment: @Kimvais: If the HTML becomes more complex then it makes sense to use inclusion tags. If there is additional logic to constructing the image path then you'd end up with that logic in your inclusion template, which is not ideal.

Comment: @cedric.salaun: That is the syntax for a filter - the solution above is a template tag which uses `{% ... %}`.

Comment: True - shouldn't you return the `<img>` tag - either as hardcoded or via `render_to_string`?

Comment: @Kimvais: Thanks, I've updated the answer to make it only return the image path string. If that is not preferred then cedric.salaun can include it in the output of `image_by_value`.

Comment: it work fine ! i return the complete img (
 return "<img src='/data/img/" + value + ".bmp' title='{% trans 'xxxxx' %}' width='16px' height='16px'>" ) it's more simple. I have a lot of icones in each page, it's great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I suggest creating a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) for it. See the part about *inclusion tags*.